# Periodical requests with Robospice

Tags: android, robospice

What is the best way to implement periodic requests in Activity using robospice (ping, for example)?

Answer (score 0):

Someone had the idea of using the retry mechanism of RoboSpice for that matter (see [Robospice retry policy custom implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463465)).

I have successfully used and would suggest using Android Alarms ([more details](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)) with a `Service` that contains a `SpiceManager`.